# Grails deployment on Heroku

Tags: git, grails, deployment, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Grails-app (1.3.7) on Heroku.

I downloaded the Heroku-plugin, added the following to the BuildConfig.groovy

```
plugins {
    compile ':heroku:1.0'
 }
```

Created a cedar stack

```
heroku create --stack cedar
```

From there I added a new remote repo by running the following:

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:<name generated during create>.git
```

After this I ran this command:

```
git push heroku master
```

And got the following result:

```
-------> Heroku receiving push
! Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
```

I have read various tutorials etc but nothing seems to work for me.

I haven't got a pom.xml-file (some say I need it, some say I don't!)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to push to the heroku-branch I installed the following plugin:

```
grails install-plugin cloud-support
```

After that I was able to move on :)

Comment: Also, don't forget to add this line to your BuildConfig.groovy: compile ":cloud-support:1.0.8"

Answer (score 2):

There are two tutorials in the docs, one basic and one more advanced, which show the steps you need to follow: http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-heroku/docs/manual/